# Unable to retrieve value in AJAX POST call. [Used AJAX, MVC ASP.net, .net framework 4.0]

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following entity

Entity AssetMgmt

```
public class AssetMgmt : CommonPropertiesViewModel
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public int TypeOfDevice { get; set; }

    public string DeviceStatus { get; set; }

    public test[] Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Entity test

```
public class test
{
    public string IMEINumber { get; set; }

    public int? SubscriptionType { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionTypeName { get; set; }

    public int CarrierId { get; set; }

    public string CarrierName { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public bool setAsPrimary { get; set; }

    public string SIMNo { get; set; }

    public string Puk1 { get; set; }

    public string Puk2 { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Maxbudget { get; set; }

    public bool SendConsumption { get; set; }
}
```

Entity CommonPropertiesViewModel

```
public class CommonPropertiesViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string CustomMessage { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

javascript function

```
function SaveNew() {
     var del = { "ClientId" : 0,
        "CreatedBy" : null,
        "CreatedOn" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
        "CustomMessage" : null,
        "DepartmentId" : 0,
        "DeviceStatus" : null,
        "Id" : 4,
        "ModifiedBy" : null,
        "ModifiedOn" : null,
        "Subscriptions" : [ { "AccountId" : 421,
              "CarrierId" : 1,
              "CarrierName" : "Airtel",
              "IMEINumber" : "352698040297280",
              "Id" : 8,
              "Maxbudget" : 250.0,
              "PhoneNo" : "9409635039",
              "Puk1" : "2415367892",
              "Puk2" : "9818067434",
              "SIMNo" : "485769351624",
              "SendConsumption" : true,
              "SubscriptionType" : 1,
              "SubscriptionTypeName" : "Voice",
              "setAsPrimary" : true
            },
            { "AccountId" : 421,
              "CarrierId" : 1,
              "CarrierName" : "Airtel",
              "IMEINumber" : "352276053001012",
              "Id" : 9,
              "Maxbudget" : 750.0,
              "PhoneNo" : "4875351547",
              "Puk1" : "9742277228",
              "Puk2" : "2789210574",
              "SIMNo" : "365289701254",
              "SendConsumption" : true,
              "SubscriptionType" : 1,
              "SubscriptionTypeName" : "Voice",
              "setAsPrimary" : true
            }
          ],
        "TypeOfDevice" : 1
      }
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#urlprefix").val() + 'AssetManagement/SaveNew',
            data: { "del": JSON.stringify(del) },
            success: function (d) {
                console.log('here');
                return false;
            },
            error: function (msg) {
            }
      });
    }
```

After doing all these...
My AJAX Call

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SaveNew(AssetMgmt del)
  {
        return View("SaveNew", del);
  }
```

When i hover on [image] highlighted area in debug mode I should get values that are sent from client side to the server.

My problem is that when i make AJAX Call I am getting no value for del. No values are received on server side. I.E. in *SaveNew(AssetMgmt del)* i get either null or blank object. 
What i want is value for **del** that is sent from client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to spe4cify the content type as JSON

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#urlprefix").val() + 'AssetManagement/SaveNew',
            data: JSON.stringify({ del: del }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (d) {
                console.log('here');
                return false;
            },
            error: function (msg) {
            }
      });
```

Comment: I don't know why i tried your answer. But didn't got able to get values. It is giving me same output... :(

Comment: How did you get the variable `del` ?

Comment: You can now revisit the question.

Comment: Can you see the request using firebug or chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get value from this way

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#urlprefix").val() + 'AssetManagement/SaveNew',
            data: JSON.stringify({ del: del }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (d) {
                 alert(d.del);
                console.log('here');
                return false;
            },
            error: function (msg) {
            }
      });
```

Comment: Tried this as well... No luck. :(

Comment: What is this ( return View("SaveNew", del) ) return ?

Comment: Debug ur controller code and check what value come in 'del' ?

Comment: I did debugging. But i am getting values for all the variables as their default value of data type or null.

Comment: return View("SaveNew", del) means I am returning the values to view name SaveNew. And values are stored in del.

Comment: u r save all value right na ? so how it can possible return value ?

Comment: All i want is to pass the value to the server. And the given code is just example which reproduces my issue...

Comment: see my below example and try that way.

Answer (score 0):

See this simple example and try that way

This is json function

```
function SaveNew() {

                var AccountId = 421;

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'SaveNew',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ AccountId : AccountId  }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.del==1)
                        {
                           alert('record saved Successfully.');
                        }  
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error Occurred');
                    }

                });
            }
        };
```

and this is controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveNew(int AccountId )
        {
           //here is save code
            var del=1;
            return Json(new { del }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is perfect work now u can add more fields like 'AccountId' and pass to controller.

Comment: Dear, I dont want single value. I want to get object with values. Otherwise i already have solution.

Comment: so u can pass list in 'del' object.

Comment: Yeah. I want to pass one object which should contain all values. And also list as mentioned in the entity AssetMgmt.

Answer (score 0):

first add list in Model of all model class

```
public class AdminList
{
        public List<AssetMgmt> ObjAssetMgmtList { get; set; }
        public List<test> ObjtestList { get; set; }
        public List<CommonPropertiesViewModel> ObjCommonPropertiesList { get; set; }

}
```

Then

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveNew(int AccountId )
        {
           AdminList admins1 = new AdminList();

           //add list in admins1 whatever u want then return

            return Json(new { admins1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Tried. Still no success. :(

Comment: What u want to display in ' console.log('here'); ' javascript function ? first clear that u r just record save or save & display list both.If u r display list then what r control used for bind ? i mean Webgrid or any control ?

Comment: see my below ans.that i have used in my project also.this work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First u take array in javascript function like

```
function SaveNew() {

        var AccountId;
        var CarrierId;
        var CarrierName;

        var del= [];

                del[0] = {
                   AccountId : 421,
                   CarrierId : 1,
                    CarrierName: "Airtel"

                 };
        }
        $.ajax({

                    url: 'SaveNew',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ del: del}),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Now u get all field value return back that add in del

                       int id=result.del.AccountId; 

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error Occurred');
                    }

                });
            }
        };
```

Then add in controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveNew(AdminList[] del)
        {
           AdminList admins1 = new AdminList();

           //here u can get field that added in del like

            int id=del[0].AccountId;

            return Json(new { admins1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: And what about Subscriptions?